# How to convert a tuple to a string in Python?

Tags: python, tuples

After a MySQL select statement, I am left with the following:

```
set([('1@a.com',), ('2@b.net',), ('3@c.com',), ('4@d.com',), ('5@e.com',), ('6@f.net',), ('7@h.net',), ('8@g.com',)])
```

What I would like to have is a

```
emaillist = "\n".join(queryresult)
```

to in the end, have a string:

```
1@a.com
2@b.net
3@c.com
etc
```

What would be the proper way to convert this nested tuple into string?

Comment: tried new = '\n'.join(old[0])  but got   TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing

Comment: Karmic -1 for assuming only dudes would answer your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As long as you're sure you have just one element per tuple:

```
'\n'.join(elem[0] for elem in queryresult)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this and see

```
>>> something=set([('1@a.com',), ('2@b.net',), ('3@c.com',), ('4@d.com',), ('5@e.com',), ('6@f.net',), ('7@h.net',), ('8@g.com',)])
>>> print '\n'.join(''.join(s) for s in something)
6@f.net
7@h.net
2@b.net
1@a.com
8@g.com
5@e.com
4@d.com
3@c.com
```

Note, join can only work on strings, but the items of the set are tuples. To make the join work, you have to iterate over the set to convert each item as string. Finally once done you can join them in the way your heart desires

On a side note. A circumbendibus way of doing it :-)

```
>>> print "\n".join(re.findall("\'(.*?)\'",pprint.pformat(something)))
1@a.com
2@b.net
3@c.com
4@d.com
5@e.com
6@f.net
7@h.net
8@g.com
```

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension along the lines of

```
[item[0] for item in queryresult]
```

should help. eg,

```
emaillist = "\n".join([item[0] for item in queryresult])
```

.. this makes strong assumptions about the type and structure of queryresult, however.

---

**edit**

A generator expression is even better at doing this:

```
emaillist = "\n".join(item[0] for item in queryresult)
```

thanks to @delnan  for this update

Comment: The list comprehension is unnecessary. Make it a generator expression and drop the parens, saves memory, characters and the reader's time: `"\n".join(item[0] for item in queryresult)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
new = '\n'.join(x[0] for x in old)
```