# python convert tuples of arbitrary length to string

Tags: python

I have tuples like this

```
tup= [('p4x8duom', 'p4x8duomtop', 'topvlrbxl0z398a')
 ('p4x8duom', 'p4x8duombot', 'topvlrbxl1z398a')]



  tup2=  [('p4x8duoend', 'p4x8duoendtop', 'toplqvlctlupr0z3a'), ('p4x8duogps', 'p4x8duogpstop', 'toprqvlctlupr0z3a'), ('p4x8duoend', 'p4x8duoendbot', 'toplqvlctlupr1z3a'), ('p4x8duogps', 'p4x8duogpsbot', 'toprqvlctlupr1z3a')]
```

I have seen this answer-for tuple of length one
[How to convert a tuple to a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704952/python-convert-tuple-to-string)
So the code below only works for one element in the tuple, how do i modify it to my pattern?

```
''.join(elem[0] for elem in tup)
```

These tuples come from reading a file.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a nested loop :

```
>>> ' '.join(i for elem in tup for i in elem)
'p4x8duom p4x8duomtop topvlrbxl0z398a p4x8duom p4x8duombot topvlrbxl1z398a'
```

If you dont want the spaces, you just can join with `''` :

```
>>> ''.join(i for elem in tup for i in elem)
'p4x8duomp4x8duomtoptopvlrbxl0z398ap4x8duomp4x8duombottopvlrbxl1z398a'
```

Comment: Damn! Beat me by a sec!

Comment: Thanks, thought it should be that but wasn't getting it right.

Comment: @Illusionist welcome, so whats your expected output?

Comment: what you gave me was exactly what  i needed.. i just needed to convert the tuple to a string to write to a file

Comment: @Illusionist sounds you don't want the spaces right?